# Explain (T,) tensor shape

Tags: pytorch, reshape

In the following [d2l tutorial](https://d2l.ai/chapter_recurrent-neural-networks/sequence.html):

```
import torch

T = 1000

time = torch.arange(1, T + 1, dtype=torch.float32)
print(f"time shape: {time.shape}")

x = torch.sin(0.01 * time) + torch.normal(0.0, 0.2, size=(T,))
```

Given that `torch.sin(0.01 * time)` shape is `torch.Size([1000])` why the `size` attribute provided to `normal` function is `(T,)` and not `(T)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `(T)` is equal to `T` having type of `int`, while `torch.normal` requires a tuple. `(T,)` is a Python way to pass one-element tuple.